# Styling custom date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, datepicker

I'm using [this](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js) datepicker plugin to display a popup datepicker.

It's *working* fine, but I'm having trouble assigning it the correct styles.

I have 2 of them, the first not being an issue.

I have the following JS:

```
$(".datepicker1").pickadate({
    min: 1,
    onClose: function() {
        var picker = $input.pickadate("picker");

        picker.set("select", this.component.item.select.pick);
        picker.open();
    }
});
```

What it does is simple: The moment a user selects a date on the first picker, the second one is displayed, with the previously selected date displayed(In order to let the user know what the range of dates will be that he/she selects).

Everything works just fine, but I don't want the default blue square background for the selected date. I want something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/z15m4mN.png) as opposed to [what I currently have](http://i.imgur.com/RbtQ3Sb.png), which is just a different `background-color`.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: please add a jsfiddle to your question http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see the markup or css, my first inclination with these is to add a CSS triangle either to the element, or to the elements :before pseudo class.

As for making the CSS triangle, go here:
http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the class

```
.picker__day--highlighted:hover, .picker--focused .picker__day--highlighted
```

in the default.date.css file. Then, you can easily modify "everything" concerning the today hightlight shape